# Showing that the integers and the rationals are numerically equivalent to each other.

Tags: functions

Provide two functions, one from the integers to the rationals, and one from the rationals to the integers. Then show your two functions are each injections.

Define $f:\mathbb{Z^+} \to \mathbb{Q^+}$ by $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

Suppose $f(x)=f(y)$. Then $\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{y} \Rightarrow x=y$. So $f$ is injective.

Define $g:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ by $g(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
       f(x) & if  \hspace{2mm} x \in \mathbb{Z^+}\\
        -f(-x) & if \hspace{2mm} x \notin \mathbb{Z^+} \\
     \end{array}
   \right.$

Consider $g(x)=g(y)$ in 3 cases:

Case 1 ($x\in\mathbb{Z^+} \wedge y \in \mathbb{Z^+}$): Then $g(x)=g(y) \Rightarrow f(x)=f(y)$. As $f$ is injective, then $f(x)=f(y) \Rightarrow x=y$.

Case 2 ($x\notin\mathbb{Z^+} \wedge y \notin \mathbb{Z^+}$): Then $g(x)=g(y) \Rightarrow -f(-x)=-f(-y) \Rightarrow -f(x)=-f(y) \Rightarrow f(x)=f(y)$. As $f$ is injective, then $f(x)=f(y) \Rightarrow x=y$.

Case 3 ($x\in\mathbb{Z^+} \wedge y \notin \mathbb{Z^+}$): WLOG assume that $x \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ and $y \notin \mathbb{Z^+}$. Then $x \ne y$. But also $g(x)=f(x)$ is positive and $g(y)=-f(-y)$ is non-positive, so $f(x) \ne f(y)$.

In each case, $g$ is injective.

I'm trying to figure out how to show that $g$ is surjective, so that I have a function from the rationals to the integers. But it hasn't been fruitful so far.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  You say that $f$ is surjective.  How do you solve $f(x)=\frac 23$?

Comment: Usually one just exhibits injections both ways and then invokes Cantor Schroeder Bernstein.  Of course explicit bijections are known but they need effort.

Comment: How would you exhibit an injection from the rationals to the integers?

Comment: Well, that's the exercise.  As a hint to get you started, note that pairs of natural numbers inject into the integers as $(a,b)\mapsto 2^a\times 3^b$, for instance.

Comment: Is that because every integer >1 can be uniquely written as a product of strictly increasing prime powers?

Comment: @lulu and that is unique to to fundamental the of arithmetic

Comment: Not sure what point you are making.  I am not talking about factoring general integers.  All you need to argue is that $2^a\times 3^b=2^c\times 3^d$ for $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb N \implies a=c,\, b=d$.  You can invoke unique factorization for that.

Comment: But I'm not sure how to use this to construct said injection.